# Any ASP.NET MVC tutorials that DON'T use unit tests or mocks?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm an ASP.NET Webforms dev, and I'm gradually easing into ASP.NET MVC. I understand the benefits of complete unit testing and the use of mocks to completely separate the different abstraction layers. But if possible, I'd like to learn the MS MVC framework all by itself first...and then incorporate unit tests (via test projects) and mock frameworks into my knowledge.

So does anyone know of books/tutorials that concentrate solely on the ASP.NET MVC framework without incorporating unit tests or mock frameworks? I've looked. TIA.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: Thanks; I've been through that one. It was a good tutorial, and is just what I'm looking for, but I was hoping there are more similar to this, just more in-depth.

Comment: I don't think you can quickly exhaust the tutorials on that site. Several chapters with examples. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like video training then take a look at pluralsight, www.pluralsight.com. The videos are broken down into sections so if there is an area you are not currently interested in then you can move on.

They also have some on the asp.net website http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos.

Comment: Wow, that looks like a good site. I've just started browsing the videos. Are they free? I didn't see any "carts" for payment. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The ones on the www.asp.net website are free. Pluralsight offer subscriptions but also free trials

Comment: Just an update, to close this thread. I just took one of my WebForms apps, converted it to an MVC project, and piece by piece, added the MVC parts I'd learned back into the converted app. Hands-on, and quite successful. [This](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/05/convert-web-forms-mvc3-how-to.html) excellent tutorial explains how to convert a WebForms app to an MVC project; it was very helpful. Thanks all.